# save files in this format

Tags: excel, vba

In the **Excel Option**, in the **Save section**, What is the difference between:

- in my Pc/excel is showing the option: **Save files in this format: Excel Workbook**
- While another PC/excel is showing like this: **Save files in this format: Excel Workbook(*.xlsx)**

How can I change the other PC/excel settings in order to show this option as:

**Save files in this format: Excel Workbook**

As this difference is making my VBA code to go in error in the other user, in particular, this part of the code:

```
dim V_WBNameOutPut as string
V_WBNameOutPut = "Test"
Application.Workbooks(V_WBNameOutPut).Activate
```

doesn't work on the other user, as it goes in error, while if add the extension

```
V_WBNameOutPut = V_WBNameOutPut & ".xlsx"
```

the code works.

Any idea?

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea to check the Excel versions on the different machines. They are probably different.

Comment: Store the workbook object in a variable that you can use to refer to instead of trying to use the filename.

Comment: This setting has nothing to do with the issue. The setting you're looking for is `Hide extensions for known file types` in windows' `Folder Options->View`. When it is enabled, you can alternatively use the file name without its extension but I wouldn't recommend it. In either case, you can use the file name including its extension which you should be aiming for.

Comment: Is this a saved vs non-saved workbook confusion? If a file isn't saved yet, you can activate it with Workbooks("Test"); if it has been saved, you'll need to add the file extension as you can have Test.Xlsx/Test.Xlsm/Test.Xls etc. (well I suppose there are two issues, the saving part and the calling the workbook part)

Comment: @Notus_Panda I wonder how you would create a never saved workbook named `Test`.

Comment: Welp, you got me there but you understood what I meant ;)

Comment: The file is saved, but the option: shows File name extensions, creates this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check the file extension display option in both systems, because it is possible that the system that requires the extension in your code has this option set to always shows the file extensions.

For Windows 8/10/11, you can open any folder, click on the "View" tab at the top of the window, then check if the "File name extension" is ticked or unticked in both systems. For Windows 7 and older, the option is in Folder Options in the Control Panel.